# Google sheet App script copy and paste with condition

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Dear All i am very new in google app script i am trying to to add condition in case if any of cell from J1 to J20 is blanks and check column H1 to H20  is not Empty copy That value from I and past it in J as value i have try below script but its not working i also attached sheet link

```
function copyIf() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = ss.getSheetByName("tab1"); 
  var condition = source.getRange('J1:J20').getValue();
  if (condition == "") {  
     source.getRange("i1:i20").copyTo(source.getRange("J1:i20"), {contentsOnly:true});
    
  } 
}
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sVatJ_ofH8-Rg7qz_5BpmJhQufH-_lLhOt3G0N-nOTk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

### Try:

```
function copyIf() {

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(`tab1`)
  const range = sheet.getRange(`H1:J20`)
  const values = range.getValues()
                      .map(row => {
                        return (row[0] && !row[2]) ? [row[0], row[1], row[1]] : row
                      })

  range.setValues(values)

}
```

### Explained:

```
function copyIf() {
  
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(`tab1`)
  // Get all three columns.
  const range = sheet.getRange(`H1:J20`)
  // Get the values of the 3 columns...
  const values = range.getValues()
                      // For each row...
                      .map(row => {
                        // Check if Col H has value, and Col J does not..
                        return (row[0] && !row[2])
                               // If true, add Col I value to Col J.
                               ? [row[0], row[1], row[1]]
                               // If false, leave it alone.
                               : row
                      })
  // Set the modified values to the range.
  range.setValues(values)

}
```

### Simplified:

(Don't use)

```
function copyIf() {

  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(`tab1`)
  
  const valuesH = sheet.getRange(`H1:H20`).getValues()
  const valuesI = sheet.getRange(`I1:I20`).getValues()
  const valuesJ = sheet.getRange(`J1:J20`).getValues()

  for (let row = 0; row < valuesI.length; row++) {
    if (valuesJ[row][0] === `` && valuesH[row][0] !== ``) {
      valuesJ[row][0] = valuesI[row][0]
    }
  }

  sheet.getRange(`J1:J20`).setValues(valuesJ)

}
```